# apt-get update is not working inside docker container

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-compose, dockerhub

I have created the container using the ubuntu:14.04.
I have set proxies in the docker file configuration.
When i start the conatiner and type command apt-get update it is giving me error.

```
root@4a7043e2f675:/# apt-get update
```

```
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com]
```

will stuck here and after for a while gives error as follow :

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

please provide me solution people.

Comment: Perhaps you could add your `Dockerfile`

Comment: For whatever reason, the proxies you set up are not working properly and your container has no internet access or dns access.

Comment: my internet is working fine in base image. and also i have added /etc/default/docker both HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY

Comment: You have not shown us your command to start the docker container. Something like `docker run -it ubuntu:14.04`. is it?

Answer (score 2):

People my problem has been solved by export proxy in the container.But I still don't understand that why their is a need of setting proxy inside container as proxy already been set for base image and also in /etc/default/docker file